# Parse php associative array to javascript object

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, object

I want to have a javascript array of "country" objects which at this stage will have only two attributes: name, and geonameId.

I get these countries from a database like so:

```
            $sql = "SELECT name, geonameId FROM countryinfo";
            $result = $conn->query($sql);
            if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
                $rows = array ();
                while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                    $country["geonameId"]);
                    $rows[$row['geonameId']] = $row['name'];
                }
            }
            $conn->close();
        ?>
```

I then have this javascript script which turns the php array into a javascript one:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var allCountries = <? echo json_encode($rows); ?>;
    console.log(allCountries);
</script>
```

I just want to turn that array of key/value pairs into an array of objects so I have easier access to new attributes that I may add in the future. At the moment the javascript array logs to the console like this:

```
Object {0: "Netherlands Antilles", 49518: "Rwanda", 51537: "Somalia", 69543: "Yemen", 99237: "Iraq", 102358: "Saudi Arabia", 130758: "Iran", 146669: "Cyprus", 149590: "Tanzania", 163843: "Syria", 174982: "Armenia", 192950: "Kenya", 203312:...
```

How do I convert that array of key/value pairs to an array from javascript objects (with refactoring, I will be adding a Country class and the array will contain Country objects).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My relevant code was changed to this to get it to work:

```
$sql = "SELECT name, geonameId FROM countryinfo";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);
    $allCountries = [];
    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        $rows = array ();
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            $country = array(
                "name" => $row['name'],
                "geonameId" => $row['geonameId']
            );
            $allCountries[] = $country;
        }
    }
    $conn->close();
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var allCountries = <?php echo json_encode($allCountries, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT) ?>;
    console.log(allCountries)
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

Simple serialize as JSON on the PHP end and then do JSON.parse in Javascript

Comment: How do I access the serialized php object from javascript? My attempt was this: `$jsonObj = json_encode($rows);
        $conn->close();
    ?>
        
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var allCountries = JSON.parse($jsonObj)`

Comment: Ideally your PHP script should bee called from the client side using XMLHttpRequest then your php script echo'es the json string, and you access the json  object using                         var myArr = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText); from the responseText property